# How to create architecture specific environments in tox

Tags: python, tox

I am creating a python C-extension which depends on architecture (32bit/64bit) specific C modules. I would like to handle them in different tox-environments. By default it is only possible to create separate environments for different python versions, but not for different architectures:

```
[testenv:py36]
...
```

Is it possible somehow to split this entry into a 32bit and a 64bit version:

```
[testenv:py36-32bit]
...

[testenv:py36-64bit]
...
```

Especially for Windows this is a big issue, as both architectures have to be supported and may be even installed in one system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays is possible without plugins. See the docs [here](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html#using-generative-section-names)

Adding the following worked for me.

```
[tox]
envlist = py38-x86,py39

[testenv]
basepython =
    py38-x86: python3.8-32
    py39: python3.9-64
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell it is not possible today. There is a discussion on the topic:

- https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/1149

---

Maybe there is a way to workaround this thanks to the [`tox-interpreters` plugin](https://pypi.org/project/tox-interpreters/):

```
[tox]
envlist =
    ThreeSixThirtyTwo-something
    ThreeSixThirtyTwo-another
    ThreeEightSixtyFour
    ThreeEightSixtyFour-again
[testenv]
interpreter =
    ThreeSixThirtyTwo.* = A:\Path\To\Python3.6-32bits\python.exe
    ThreeEightSixtyFour.* = B:\Path\To\Python3.8-64bits\python.exe
commands =
    python -V
    python -c "import platform; print(platform.architecture())"
```